# How to enable TLS 1.1 in apache Karaf

Tags: jboss, apache-karaf

Can you guide me How to enable TLS 1.1 in apache Karaf.

Thanks,
Abdul Wahid

Comment: See an answer to your question [HERE](http://serverfault.com/questions/314858/how-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-with-openssl-and-apache)

Comment: Where do you need TLS: for jmx, for the console? Access to the CLI is already over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented at the pax web documentation which can be found [here](http://ops4j.github.io/pax/web/SNAPSHOT/User-Guide.html#ssl-configuration)